# Rails ActiveModel - Updating nested attributes and adding new ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm a Rails beginner. What I have right now is a `Form` that `has_many` approvals.

```
class Form < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :form_results
 has_many :approvals

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :approvals
end
```

```
class Approval < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :form
 belongs_to :user
end
```

When editing `:approvals` I need to run some logic. Approvals are sequential so they have an `order_index` as well as an `active` key (similar to a soft delete). When a `FormResult` gets created, multiple `FormResultApprovals` get created based on the data in `Approvals` for that form. What I need to do when updating the Form, I need to see if an Approval has changed for an already existing `order_index`. If it has I need to mark the existing Approval as `active: false` and create a new `Approval` for that `order_index`.

I'm wondering what the "Rails way" of doing this is? I have a big chunk of logic that checks all of this and works, but as I discover more and more Rails helpers, I can't help but think there's a better way to do this.

The code I have now looks like

```
# Grab all current approvals for form that is being edited
# Diff the current against the new ones in the attributes
# If any have of the current approvals have the same id as the "new" ones in the attributes but have a different user associated to them, set active to false on the current approval with that id, and insert a new approval associated to the new user.
```

I'm using SimpleForm.

Comment: Can you specify a bit more about which part of the process you are looking for guidance on? Or maybe post some of the code for the logic so we can see what you are currently doing, and thus if there is a more "rails" way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt I just edited it show the approval model and the current logic I have. I'm having trouble seeing how I can use `update_attributes` on the form, but add custom logic for the nested `approval` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with.

```
class Approval < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { where(active: true) }
  belongs_to :form_module
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :group, optional: true

  before_update :handle_change_in_approver


  def create_copy_model
    new_approval = Approval.new(order_index: order_index, user_id: user_id, group_id: group_id, form_module_id: form_module_id)
    new_approval.save
    self.active = false
    self.user_id = user_id_was
    self.group_id = group_id_was
    save
  end

  def handle_change_in_approver
    # User ID changed
    if user_id_was != user_id
      create_copy_model
    elsif group_id_was != group_id
      create_copy_model
    end
    form.form_results.each(&:create_approvals_for_approval_change)
  end
end
```

Basically, whenever a record is updated I run a callback before the update that checks to see if the group_id or user_id has changed. If it has then I create a new `Approval` based on the update params, and the return the current `Approval` back to it's original state, marking it as `active: false`. I'm pretty stoked with how this turned out.